# Data type combining other data types with tuple? Syntax needed - Haskell

Tags: haskell

just a quick question as I'm not sure how to symatically go about this:

I've made a test to show you what I mean;
I have

```
type Teacher    = String
type Assitant   = String
data Student    = String Int
```

The data they will contain will be:
Teacher's name
Assistant's name
Student's name, age

--

I want to make another data called 'Classroom' but I'm not sure how I can contain all these types within the 'Classroom' data?
So far I have:

```
data Classroom = Classroom Teacher Assistant [Student]
```

i.e. "Mrs. Cloud" "Terrence" [("Amy, 19), ("Paul", 20), ("Scott", 20)]

Cany anyone help me to change my Classroom data to allow the entry above?
Many thanks,
Mike

Comment: `data Student = Student String Int; data Classroom = Classroom Teacher Assistant [Student]`

Answer (score 1):

Your `Classroom` datatype is correct. But you need `Student` datatype either to have a constructor (as `Classroom`): `data Student = Student String Int` or to be a tuple synonym: `type Student = (String, Int)`. The latter one matches to your example (just don't forget constructor of `Classroom`).

Comment: I would also add a type for "Age" and "Name" to make later functions clear.

Comment: Thanks Yuuri, just what I was looking for! 
Yes Komikus it was type not data but I think that was a typo :)